# How Does Bootstrap Decide what "col" class to use?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm working on a new framework for a project. Usually I just use my own framework but this calls for a more bootstrap style layout (bootstrap isn't applicable though) where you can have "col-lg, col-md, col-xs" type of sizing.

My question is if I have a div that is...

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
     <p>Some content</p>
 </div>
```

How does the browser know at what point the styling for the "col-lg-12" should be implemented?

My first thought is a media query...but then in this case i'd essentially be saying "stop doing the col-sm-6 stuff and do the col-lg-12 stuff" which would work for this one instance but would break all the other col-sm-6 that might be active on the page that should behave normally.

Anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Media queries ... Use the inspector tools

Comment: Yes, bootstrap just enable piece of code with the help media query and all code is always there in css file, it's just matter of overiding the main class case to other which gets priority now.

Comment: What i mean is HOW does it know, it's not like one is an id and the other is a class. Whats to stop the one you dont want from taking precedence over the other?

Comment: In this case you have 2 options, either remove that am class where you don't need it or give its value to behave like lg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ALWAYS implemented. The smaller sizes just act as overrides when their media query kicks in.

```
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6"></div>

 .col-md-12{
     width:100%;
 }

 @media all and (max-width: 768px){
   .col-sm-6{
     width:50%;
 }
 }
```

This will apply 100% width until the screen is below 768 width, at which point the width in the media query takes over.

Comment: Ah ok so that's how it's done. Figured it was something pretty straight forward but thought i'd double check! Thanks for the response man!

Comment: I wondered the same thing before so I dug into the CSS. I would recommend doing so as well if you are attempting to build your own responsive framework. You will pick up a lot of tricks digging through their source that you can take advantage of in your own.